# textFieldDidEndEditing not recognising text in textfields correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am trying to detect a change in text in a `textField` and I have a peculiar error. The code below compares the impactLabel1 text with a variable impactlabel1 previously set. If there is a change in the `textField` so that does not equal the variable then the setHeadingsButton shows. This works perfectly if there is a single word with no spaces in the `texfield`. However if there are two words it thinks that they are not equal even when they are the same. The `NSLog` displays both values as the same also.

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textView
{
NSLog (@"%@", impactLabel1.text);
NSLog (@"%@", impactlabel1);    

if (impactLabel1.text != impactlabel1)
{
    [setHeadingsButton setAlpha:1];
}
    NSLog (@"%@", impactLabel1.text);
    NSLog (@"%@", impactlabel1);
}
```

Comment: The `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method is called when the text field is no longer the first responder, not when the text changes.

Comment: I understand that, and when it is called it compares the values to check if the values are now different - ie it has changed. My query is that is works when there is one word in the text field but not when there are spaces, even though the two values are identical (as shown in the NSLog).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use isEqualToString method instead of "!=" operator. That operator compares pointers, not actual string values.

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textView
{
NSLog (@"%@", impactLabel1.text);
NSLog (@"%@", impactlabel1);    

if (![impactLabel1.text isEqualToString: impactlabel1])
{
    [setHeadingsButton setAlpha:1];
}
    NSLog (@"%@", impactLabel1.text);
    NSLog (@"%@", impactlabel1);
}
```

Comment: But I do not want the button to appear if they are equal. I want it to appear if they are not equal, prompting the user to save the change that they have made.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths That's what the `!` (not) is for. This is the correct answer to see if the two string values are different.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths This is why I used ![impactLabel1.text isEqualToString: impactlabel1] instead of [impactLabel1.text isEqualToString: impactlabel1]. ! is a negation.

Comment: My apologies - I didn't read that properly the first time. Perfect - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if (![impactLabel1.text isEqualToString:impactlabel1) ...
```

Might also recommend you use some other name for the impactlabel1 NSString* variable since it's could easily be confused with the impactLabel1 UILabel* object

Comment: In retrospect yes - I totally agree. All working now though - thanks